# Flex left element position to the top

Tags: css, layout, flexbox, css-float

How can I place the blue box next to red box at the top. The yellow box should be below the blue box.

I cannot change the HTML structure. And also I cannot use margin-top for the blue box because the height of the boxes will change dynamically.

Please help me! Thanks!

Here is my code:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

.item {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item1 {
  width: 60%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: red;
}

.item2 {
  width: 60%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

.item3 {
  width: 30%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.item4 {
  width: 30%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item item1"></div>
  <div class="item item2"></div>
  <div class="item item3"></div>
  <div class="item item4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why you don't using **display: flex;** with orders? So first red, then blue, yellow and what about green item?

Answer (score -1):

there is a typo error in your CSS file.

in your second item selector, you wrote `itme2`, and here is the problem.

❌`.itme2 {...}`
✅`.item2 {...}`

> the logic is fine! is just a typo

[image]

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

.item {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item1 {
  width: 60%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: red;
}

.item2 {
  width: 60%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

.item3 {
  width: 30%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.item4 {
  width: 30%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item item1"></div>
  <div class="item itme2"></div>
  <div class="item item3"></div>
  <div class="item item4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I fixed it but I don't see the layout in the image above.

Comment: here is the code I used to make it work: https://github.com/Laaouatni/stackoverflow-my-answers/tree/main/123 , maybe there is something more that I don't listed in the answer.

Comment: ok. I will add a code snippet now, is working also in code snippet